# The several new types does not work in my typescript file on Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, terminal

I made three new instances in decorator.ts, but I cannot see the expected result on Terminal. I missppelled the spell of decorator at that time. So, do not worry about the misspell.   Would anyone tell me what is wrong, please?

decolator.ts

```
function Logging(constructor: Function) {
  console.log('Logging...');
  console.log(constructor);
}
@Logging
class User {
  name = 'Quill';
  constructor() {
    console.log('User was created!');
  }
}

const user1 = new User();
const user2 = new User();
const user3 = new User();
```

decolator.js

```
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
function Logging(constructor) {
    console.log('Logging...');
    console.log(constructor);
}
let User = class User {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Quill';
        console.log('User was created!');
    }
};
User = __decorate([
    Logging
], User);
```

I typed "node dist/decolator.js

the result of terminal

```
Logging...
[class User]
```

The ideal result of terminal should be

```
Logging...
[Function: User]
User was created!
User was created!
User was created!
```

Comment: Did you recompile after you made the changes to your .ts file?

Comment: Yes, I did. I will add decolator.js here.

Comment: Yeah, you didn't compile your TS after you made changes. There's no instantiation of that class going on in your output JS, and your code works as intended for me in the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGTgczTMaAUEEDOUATiNHMQFyIBi408YAlIgN4BQii+YBcANgFMAdP3Q4A5KgxY0w+RKYBuTt0ICRY3DyKlyxZewC+7AALTM2dhH4BDAgUQBVAoOJtVYWwFtBiALyIEgCKIDD8-BIqXDokZFAUOCwcXDHqQqLiEi5uiADu9tzEgrZQggAmAISK0YgmJtaEUIggrsQAjAGIYIJ5zm1JKrEtbQBMXT19OcSDjbzNrW4AzBO9-W6DQA

Comment: @JaredSmith Oops. Yes, you are right. I was in Starbucks and the internet connection was down since I kept programming for an hour. So, the connection was disconnected. After re-loading a browser, it worked. I appreciate that you checked my code on the playground!!